# Фильтр в очереди проверок "Голоса за закрытие" не работает

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

Собственно, проблему демонстрирует скриншот - флажок *Необходимо конкретизировать* убран, а вопрос с этой причиной закрытия пришёл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или я неправильно понимаю принцип работы фильтров в очередях проверок?

*PS: Фильтр был применён задолго до этой проверки.*

Comment: А сбоку незаметно проглядывается напоминание об активации Windows :)

Comment: Ещё в варианте "закрыть" точка стоит до скобки, а не после неё.

Comment: @Зонтик, а куда ж мне девать эту активацию Windows? Насчёт точки - надо будет баг завести.

Comment: @wchistow, ничего не нужно заводить - [с точкой всё нормально](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/443403/190114).